# SyntaxError from definition of nested dictionary

Tags: python

I've been making this game for a while now, but I keep having this reoccurring issue. For some reason, the first bracket isn't tagged with the last bracket, making it unable to run. Does anybody have a fix for this issue? The syntax error is on the last line where I put an asterisk `*` to make it easy to find.

```
game = {'Room 1':
           {'occupant': 'Narrator',
            'option': 
               {'text': 'Do you want to start? (Yes or No)',
               'Yes': 'Milwaukee',
               'No': 'Dumpsterr'
               }
       },
     {'Milwaukee':
       {'occupant': 'Giannis',
        'option': 
           {'text': 'Do you want to go hit the weight room?(Yes or No)',
           'Yes': 'Weight Room',
           'No': 'Dumpster'
           }                
       },           
     {'Weight Room':
       {'occupant': 'Giannis',
        'option': 
           {'text': 'Lets get started (Yes or No)',
           'Yes': 'Giannis Thanksgiving party',
           'No': 'Dumpster'
           }                
       },
      {'John Hammond':
       {'occupant': 'John Hammond',
        'option': 
           {'text': 'Hey your taking up my valuabe XBOX time. Intrested in this team yes or no?(Yes or No)',
           'Yes': 'Draft',
           'No': 'Undrafted'
           } 
       },
      {'John Hammond house':
       {'occupant': 'John Hammond wife',
        'option': 
           {'text': 'Welcome to the Hammond house hold! Hi honey would you like some cookies? -  Mrs.Hammond(Yes or No)',
           'Yes': 'Draft Day',
           'No': 'How Dare You'
           } 
       },
      {'Draft Day':
       {'occupant': 'Adam Silver',
        'option': 
           {'text': 'Welcome to the NBA draft! With the tenth overall pick you have been selected? Do you accept (Yes or No)',
           'Yes': 'Winner',
           'No': 'Undrafted'
           } 
       },
      {'Dumpster':
       {'occupant': 'Dennis Rodman',
        'option': 
           {'text': 'Welcome to the dumpster! I know im a fool. To get away you have to restart. Would you like to restart?. (Yes or No)',
           'Yes': 'Room 1',
           'No': 'Dumpster'
           }
       },
      {'How dare you':
       {'occupant': 'John Hammond',
        'option': 
           {'text': 'How dare you disrespect my wifes cooking you monster! Good luck now getting draft idiot. Would you like to restart? -  John Hammond(Yes or No)',
           'Yes': 'Room 1',
           'No': 'Room 1'
           } 
       },
      {'Undrafted':
       {'occupant': 'Nobody',
        'option': 
           {'text': 'You had your chance... would you like a redo? (Yes or No)',
           'Yes': 'Room 1',
           'No': 'Undrafted'
           } 
     *  }
```

Comment: You have a trailing comma. That would cause an error. You should post the full traceback of the error you receive, without we are guessing!!

Comment: At the end of this code, there's a dangling comma and at least three unclosed braces.  I think you haven't pasted all of your code.

Comment: That took care of the dangling comma, but you now have a superfluous asterisk on the last line, and open braces as I just mentioned.

Comment: I put the asterisk to show the issue, but can you point out where the open braces are. I'm sorry, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You have an unclosed brace in each section of data.  For instance:

```
  {'How dare you':
   {'occupant': 'John Hammond',
    'option': 
       {'text': 'How dare you disrespect my wifes cooking you monster! Good luck now getting draft idiot. Would you like to restart? -  John Hammond(Yes or No)',
       'Yes': 'Room 1',
       'No': 'Room 1'
       } 
   },
  {'Undrafted':
   {'occupant': 'Nobody',
    'option': 
       {'text': 'You had your chance... would you like a redo? (Yes or No)',
       'Yes': 'Room 1',
       'No': 'Undrafted'
       } 
 *  }
```

You haven't closed the sections headed "How dare you" or "Undrafted".  Each has three left braces and only two right braces.  It looks as if every section of your data suffers from this problem.

BTW, any reasonably intelligent text editor will match braces for you.  Even **vim** does it.  :-)

Comment: lol thank you, I'm a newbie at all of this so I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @WYXZANDER if this answer helped you — you can always say *thanks* by marking answers as **Accepted Answer** ✅